# what happens to jsf components after render attribute is updated

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Given the following scenario : A jsf component's (e.g a CommandButton) render attribute depends on an application scoped managed property. Since the property is shared across all sessions, the following might easily happen : User A loads a jsf page and the button's render attribute is true, so it is rendered. Now user B also loads the page and the render attribute is still true. Now user A clicks the button which causes the property to change its value and the button is not rendered anymore. User B still has the old view and although the render attribute is false now, he can click the button because he didn't update his view in the meantime. What happens now if user B clicks the button?

I thought the button's action is fired anyway because the render attribute is just used for rendering the button and has no influence anymore, once the page is rendered. But after doing some tests it seems to me that the render attribute is also checked again after clicking the button and if the attribute is false then, the action is not performed. Can someone confirm this ?

Comment: Why in the first place would you bind the `rendered` attribute to a `@ApplicationScoped` bean? What kind of functional requirement would you achieve with this?

Comment: On a page where resources are shared it should be possible for every user to perform actions on the resources. But after such an action is performed once it should not be performed ever again. For example create a file based on the resource. Once the file is created the existing file should be used and it shouldn't be possible to create it again so the button shouldn't be displayed neither

Comment: So you can create the file once per application deployment or once based on file existence?

Comment: well both...File generation can last up to 24 h, so the application has to keep a list of which files are being processed. And after the file exists, a Downloadlink is shown

Comment: It looks like a job for a `@ViewScoped` managed bean that checks if the file exists before creating it (and other rules). If the file already exists, then this bean could not render the `<h:commandButton>`, in case it's rendered, you can show a message through `<h:message>` or a best suited way (a popup panel or anything else).

Comment: yes I implemented it this way but then above question raised where user B not yet has his view updated

Comment: I can't drectly explain why you find this behavior, but I guess you could find your own answer by looking this BalusC article: [Debug JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'll ignore the strange design for now.

> *But after doing some tests it seems to me that the render attribute is also checked again after clicking the button and if the attribute is false then, the action is not performed. Can someone confirm this ?*

Yes, that's correct. This is part of safeguard against possibly tampered requests wherein the hacker is trying to simulate the invocation of an action component which is actually not rendered by the server side (such as an admin-only command button which is only rendered when the current user has the admin role). The `rendered` (and `disabled` and `readonly`) attributes are always re-checked during processing the form submit.

In your particular case, you'd like to have a **copy** of the condition responsible for the `rendered` attribute in the view scope so that only this copy will be used as long as you're interacting with the same view. This can be achieved by just injecting the application scoped property as a managed property of a view scoped managed bean and then referencing it in the `rendered` attribute instead.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ViewBean {

    @ManagedProperty("#{appBean.rendered}")
    private boolean rendered;

    // ...
}
```

with

```
<h:commandButton ... rendered="#{viewBean.rendered}" />
```

Comment: ok but I would then force users to work on a (possibly) outdated copy of the actual application status. Can't I use the mechanism you describe above to implement collaborative work on the same resources. Or is the update process of the render attribute not fast enough for this? I would then however still be able to catch the exception in my own code

Comment: Either perform a redirect after post, or manually/automatically update the property in action(listener) method. This has nothing to do with speed, but more with the right moment in the JSF lifecycle.